# preventing other apps from accessing my files

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a few applications say a browser, a email client etc. My application can download files. Now my requirement is that, the files that are downloaded from my app should be visible/available only to any of my apps. How can i prevent other applications from accessing my data? It should not be visible through those file explorer apps either. How can i achieve this? 
I read about using the SharedUserId attribute in the manifest.xml is this relevant to me?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:sharedUserId="android.uid.shared"
android:sharedUserLabel="@string/sharedUserLabel">
</manifest>
```

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := shared

Comment: You can use prograurd .

Comment: proguard? I am not sure if thats right! as far as i know,  PROGUARD is for obfuscating, compressing etc

Comment: With the help of proguard you protect your private dir as well source code.